# batch that generates passwords using predefined Words and a random number between 1 and 99

Tags: batch-file, passwords

I am not a programmer, I need a simple bat application, that generates random Passwords with predefined words and numbers between 1 and 99.
For example I define the words "jumper", "donkey" and "Format", and the application should output Passwords like "jumper25" or "format91".
The words should all have 6 alpha characters with 2 digits, the final Password 8.
Of course it should be possible for me to add further words.

I hope somebody has a solution to this, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please add more. Will this just set a password with a name and 2 digits? That all?

Comment: how do you define these words? Write them in file , they will be prompted , as arguments to the script?

Comment: I would write them directly in the file.

Comment: I'm going to come back in a few hours (4 or 5) and check on this.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try :

```
@echo off

:: The List of name
set "$List=jumper format donkey"

for %%a in (%$List%) do call:pass %%a
pause
exit/b

:pass
set /a $Random=%random% %% 99+1
set "$Random=0%$Random%"
set "$Password=%1%$Random:~-2%"
echo %$Password%
```

**EDIT :**

To pick a word randomly in the List :

```
@echo off

:: The List of name
set "$List=jumper format donkey"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "$NbElem="

::Count the number of element in the LIST
for %%a in (%$List%) do set /a $NbElem+=1

set "$c=1"
set /a $R=%random% %% !$NbElem!+1

for %%a in (%$List%) do (
  if !$c!==!$R! call:pass %%a
  set /a $c+=1)
pause
exit/b

:pass
set /a $Random=%random% %% 99+1
set "$Random=0%$Random%"
set "$Password=%1%$Random:~-2%"
echo %$Password%
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the Problem is, when I copy the code in a text file an save it as a .bat file, the cmd Windows opens and directly Closes again.

Comment: You made something wrong. This code work fine. Try to save it as ANSI.

Comment: @pptrooper It will surely exit automatically. Why? Because you did not add `pause` at the end of the code.

Comment: @dark fang You're right ! @pptrooper check the code corrected with a `pause`

Comment: Ok it works now, just one more Thing, I want the Passwort to be generated randomly with words, now it generates it with the first word in the list, is this somwhow possible?

Comment: do you mean a password 100 % random letter and num ? Or it will pick up a word randomly in the List ?

Comment: So that it just picks a word randomly in the list.

Comment: If it's not my computer is going crazy, the random number `%$Random%` increased as you run it at the next time. When the number reaches 100, it start again from 00. 0_o

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Not as elegant as the previous but should work as intended.

EDIT: I updated the code.  It runs much faster now if you need to enclose it into a loop and generate more than one password.  Also wanted to show that it will work with most special characters as well.  At this point it will not work with the exclamation, colon and probably the pipe.  I can probably work around that as well.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM GET NUMBER OF WORDS IN THE FILE
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=[]:" %%G IN ('findstr /R /C:"^:::......$" "%~f0" ^|find /N /V ""') do SET "WORD%%G=%%H" &SET NUMWORDS=%%G

REM GET RANDOM NUMBER between 1 -99
set /a RAND_NUM=%random% %% 99 + 1

REM ADD LEADING ZERO IF NUMBER IS LESS THAN 10
IF %RAND_NUM% LSS 10 SET RAND_NUM=0%RAND_NUM%

REM GET A RANDOM NUMBER TO CHOSE ONE OF THE PASSWORDS
SET /A RAND_WORD_NUM=%RANDOM% %% %NUMWORDS% + 1 

ECHO !WORD%RAND_WORD_NUM%!%RAND_NUM%

pause

GOTO :EOF

:::jumper
:::donkey
:::format
:::passwd
:::&*^,$;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only generates Passwords with the number 35, not with random numbers.

Comment: @pptrooper, I added the output from when I run it in a loop.

Comment: When I Close the bat file and open it again, it has always the same number with random words.

Comment: @pptrooper, I changed one line of code above.  Give it a try.

Comment: @pptrooper, I could also change it so that you do not have to put three colons in front of the words if you do not like that.

Comment: Thats not necessary, now it works just fine, thanks for the code!

Comment: @pptrooper, I updated the code.  It runs much faster now. Also works with special characters.